# Is the war to protect the State of Israel from attacks from terrrorists a Milchemes Mitzvah

Tags: rambam, mitzvah, army-military-war, israel

The Rambam in [Melachim 5:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Kings_and_Wars.5.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that one of the cases of Milchemes Mitzvah is coming to the aid of Jews being attacked by an enemy.

Does that mean that the war in Gaza (declared on 07/10/2023) is a Milchemes Mitzvah? What practical differences does this Halachic status create on Jews around the world, if it is a Milchemes Mitzvah?

Comment: Relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103539/does-milchemet-mitzvah-obligatory-war-require-a-king

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150174/discussion-on-question-by-yehuda-is-the-war-to-protect-the-state-of-israel-from); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 7):

R Shlomo Aviner rules this war is a *milchemes mitzvah* ([Headlines Podcast #441](http://podcast.headlinesbook.com/e/11423-%E2%80%93-shiur-441-%E2%80%93-prisoner-exchange-in-halacha-hear-from-a-brother-of-one-of-the-hostages/) at 49:44).

> According to the Ramban, protecting the land is a mitzvah. According
> to the Rambam protecting is a mitzvah, even without Sanhedrin and
> prophets. It is a mitzvah to save Jews and save the land.

[R Yitzchak Breitowitz](https://tikvahfund.org/faculty/rabbi-yitzchak-breitowitz/) rules similarly (as you can hear on [this podcast](https://rabbiaubreyhersh.podbean.com/e/yishmael-vs-yisrael-v-the-harder-questions-feat-r-yitzchok-breitowitz/) right after the 5-minute mark)

> ... One type of a *milchemes mitzvah* is one to protect the Jewish
> people against an enemy seeking their destruction ... under any
> definition, Hamas is such an enemy. It clearly falls in the category
> of a *milchemes mitzvah* ...

I would also note this particular war is a defensive war, one where Israel was attacked on its own land and is trying to protect against further attacks (be they rockets or by land). Israel explicitly mentioned they were not looking to conquer Gaza.

Answer (score -1):

According to rambam you need a melech so it won’t be a milchemet mitzvah

Comment: This would be more useful with a precise citation

Comment: Rambam hilchos melachim perek 5 Halacha 1 Sefer hamitzvot shabsi frenkel edition page 202

Comment: This is not what the Rambam writes there, he writes that a King should wage milkhemet mitzva before other wars. The Rambam writes doesn't write that only a King can wage a milchemet mitzva. And indeed modern poskim have spoken of wars in Israel as *milkhmet mitsva* - as the Rambam describes it: "a war fought to assist Israel from an enemy which attacks them."

Comment: But if you look at the source in Sefer hamitzvot over there it’s clear that you need a king

Comment: I wonder if anyone has sources from poskim that are not religious Zionist about these wars being a milchemet mitzvah

Comment: R Yitzchok Breitowitz, a haredi posek in Jerusalem, explicitly discusses this topic incl the Rambam and rules this is a milchemet mitzva. See audio [here](https://rabbiaubreyhersh.podbean.com/e/yishmael-vs-yisrael-v-the-harder-questions-feat-r-yitzchok-breitowitz/) shortly after the 5 minute mark

Comment: This answer would be a great deal more compelling if you'd [edit] in clear citations and quotations of your sources, followed with your analysis of them.

Comment: Yes I got that passage in the rambam from rabbi breitowitz in a shiur that he gave where he said that according to rambam it wouldn’t be a milchemet mitzvah

Comment: Even though in the shiur you’re talking about he said even according to rambam you could say it is